# Кастомное правило валидации Laravel

Tags: laravel

Я написал кастомное правило проверки ИНН по примеру из [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Используется оно таким способом:

```
"inn" => ["nullable", new Inn],
```

Я хочу заменить `new Inn` на запись в одну строчку:

```
"inn" => "nullable|inn",
```

Как это сделать? Сейчас выдается ошибка

```
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateInn does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете сервис-провайдер и пишите там свой валидатор, пример [здесь](https://medium.com/@bvipul/custom-validation-rule-laravel-80a81b6a3e00).

P.S. Просто интересно, а чем плох способ с new Inn?

Comment: Правила валидации лежат в БД и меняются с помощью админки.